# Подскажите библиотеку для редактирования аудио на c++

Tags: c++, аудио, поиск-библиотек

Нужна библиотека/фреймворк для редактирования аудио-файлов(обрезка,слияние,запись). Можете подсказать? Желательно, с документацией.

Comment: посмотрите ffmpeg, вроде там есть нужный функционал

Comment: Да, ffmpeg, она же libav. Но это чистый Си, который, конечно, без особых проблем можно встроить в C++ код.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, cppreference.com подсказывает: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]